# Getting error while using live currency conversion API by Retrofit in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, http, retrofit

// This is my MainActivity.java

```
ublic class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private TextView result;
private EditText currency;
private Button button;
private static String BASE_URL = "https://api.currencyscoop.com/v1/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: called");
    initViews();
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void initViews(){
    Log.d(TAG, "initViews: called");
    result = findViewById(R.id.result);
    currency = findViewById(R.id.amount);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: called");
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RetrofitClient retrofitClient = retrofit.create(RetrofitClient.class);
    Call<ConvertAmt> calling = retrofitClient.getConvertedValue("my_api_key","USD", "INR", currency.getText().toString());
    calling.enqueue(new Callback<ConvertAmt>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ConvertAmt> call, Response<ConvertAmt> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: called :----------------------> "+response.body().getResult());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ConvertAmt> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: --------------> "+t.getStackTrace());
        }
    });
}
```

}

// This is my RetrofitClient interface

```
public interface RetrofitClient {

@GET("/convert?")
Call<ConvertAmt> getConvertedValue(@Query("api_key") String api_key, @Query("base") String base, @Query("to") String to, @Query("amount") String amount);
```

}

// This is my ConvertAmt class (Model class where i am storing the result)

public class ConvertAmt {
private double result;

```
public ConvertAmt(double result) {
    this.result = result;
}

public double getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(double result) {
    this.result = result;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ConvertAmt{" +
            "result=" + result +
            '}';
}
```

}

// This is my StackTrace

```
2020-08-27 23:59:53.212 1471-1471/com.example.online_currency W/System.err: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $
```

2020-08-27 23:59:53.212 1471-1471/com.example.online_currency W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:1401)
2020-08-27 23:59:53.212 1471-1471/com.example.online_currency W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:549)
2020-08-27 23:59:53.212 1471-1471/com.example.online_currency W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:425)
2020-08-27 23:59:53.212 1471-1471/com.example.online_currency W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:205)
2020-08-27 23:59:53.212 1471-1471/com.example.online_currency W/System.err:     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:39)
2020-08-27 23:59:53.212 1471-1471/com.example.online_currency W/System.err:     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
2020-08-27 23:59:53.213 1471-1471/com.example.online_currency W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:223)
2020-08-27 23:59:53.213 1471-1471/com.example.online_currency W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:121)
2020-08-27 23:59:53.213 1471-1471/com.example.online_currency W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:206)
2020-08-27 23:59:53.213 1471-1471/com.example.online_currency W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
2020-08-27 23:59:53.213 1471-1471/com.example.online_currency W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
2020-08-27 23:59:53.213 1471-1471/com.example.online_currency W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
2020-08-27 23:59:53.213 1471-1471/com.example.online_currency W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the data you are expecting from the response is not matching to the pojo that you are mapping
this is what you are expecting,

```
public class ConvertAmt { 
 private double result;
}
```

actual response is

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200,
        "disclaimer": "Usage subject to terms: https://currencyscoop.com/terms"
    },
    "response": {
        "timestamp": 1598589131,
        "date": "2020-08-27",
        "from": "USD",
        "to": "INR",
        "amount": "10",
        "value": 738.1371942
    }
}
```

So you can convert your pojo to

```
public class ConvertAmt { 
 private Map<String,Object> meta;
 private Map<String,Object> response;

}
```

and you can get the response like this

```
Call<ConvertAmt> calling = retrofitClient.getConvertedValue("my_api_key","USD", "INR", currency.getText().toString());


calling.getResponse().get("amount");
```

Comment: ok now got it completely and what about my RetrofitClient interface! is it okay

Comment: hey @saifali i just got my desired output but it shows me this for few seconds " : No Network Security Config specified, using platform default " and then i'm getting the output.....what to do but its not an error its related to network